# Output luma and chroma data in txt format

Tags: ffmpeg

Good day!

I would like to know if there's a way to get Y/luma values in txt format

here it is the command line
-https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-105

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#signalstats-1

and one more thing I would like to know the way to get all YUV min/max values at once

thanx

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a less verbose log level and append the command with `> output.txt`:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -f lavfi movie=input.mp4,signalstats -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.signalstats.YMIN,lavfi.signalstats.YLOW,lavfi.signalstats.YAVG,lavfi.signalstats.YHIGH,lavfi.signalstats.YMAX,lavfi.signalstats.UMIN,lavfi.signalstats.ULOW,lavfi.signalstats.UAVG,lavfi.signalstats.UHIGH,lavfi.signalstats.UMAX,lavfi.signalstats.VMIN,lavfi.signalstats.VLOW,lavfi.signalstats.VAVG,lavfi.signalstats.VHIGH,lavfi.signalstats.VMAX > output.txt
```

You can change the output format with the [`-of` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Main-options).

Comment: Ok thats work,
but is there any way to get U & V values as well beside Y values in one output.txt?